# Cygwin: Get process state

Tags: cygwin, ps

When I run `top` in Cygwin I get:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
```

I would like to extract these columns for all processes:

```
PID PPID S COMMAND
```

`ps` gives PID, PPID, and COMMAND, but how do I get the 'S' column for all processes?

Edit:

I cannot use what I use on GNU/Linux:

```
$ ps -e -o pid,ppid,state,comm
ps: unknown option -- o
Try `ps --help' for more information.

$ ps --version
ps (cygwin) 1.7.33
Show process statistics
Copyright (C) 1996 - 2014 Red Hat, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ ps --help
Usage: ps [-aefls] [-u UID] [-p PID]

Report process status

 -a, --all       show processes of all users
 -e, --everyone  show processes of all users
 -f, --full      show process uids, ppids
 -h, --help      output usage information and exit
 -l, --long      show process uids, ppids, pgids, winpids
 -p, --process   show information for specified PID
 -s, --summary   show process summary
 -u, --user      list processes owned by UID
 -V, --version   output version information and exit
 -W, --windows   show windows as well as cygwin processes

With no options, ps outputs the long format by default

procps
:
version: 3.2.8-3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became the solution:

```
perl -ne '/Name/ and print"\n";/(Name|Pid|Ppid|State):\s+(\S+)/ and print "$2\t";' /proc/*/status
```

Thanks for agtoever for inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

By default `top` does not show the PPID (at least in CygWin). Besides that, you can use the batch mode of top by using the `-b` switch in combination with the `-n 1` switch (run once). I used `awk` to skip the first lines and do a rough selection of the columns.

`top -b -n 1 | awk 'NR>6 { print $1, $8, $12 }'`

Comment: That seems to work, but is awfully slow (600 ms vs, ps' 20 ms). Can `top` be sped up?

Comment: 600 ms (or 0,6 sec) is about the same performance I get; top is slow, not awk. Also, on my Debian it goes really fast. I tried strace to find out what kernel calls it was lagging on, but that gave no much insight. I suppose the interaction between CygWin and the underlying Windows OS is causing the delay. No clue why ps is much faster though.

Comment: With a bit more hacking (batch script) you could read out all `/proc/<pid>/status` files, showing all the columns you need.

Comment: `grep State /proc/*/status` seems pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ps -e -o pid,ppid,state,comm`

Comment: See my edit why that does not work.

Comment: What does `ps --help` gives you?

Comment: See edit for --help

Comment: Note that the OP is using Cygwin, which uses a striped down version of ps.